# Custom Authorization with Parameters Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, authorize-attribute

Can someone show me how to use the parameter in Customize AuthorizeAttribute?

Like this:

```
[Authorize(Role="Admin,Supervisor")]

[Authorize(User="Me,You")]

[Authorize(Action="abc,def")]
```

This is my code now and I dont have any idea yet how to add the parameter here.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        ApplicationDbContext _context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {

            if (AuthorizeRequest(actionContext))
            {

                return;

            }

            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (((System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User).Identity).IsAuthenticated)
            {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                    Content = new StringContent("You are unauthorized to access this resource")
                };

            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
            }
        }

        private bool AuthorizeRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var action = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

            var controller = actionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;

            var currentUser = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.GetUserId();

            var user = _context.Users.Join(_context.UserAccesses, x => x.RoleId, y => y.RoleId, (x, y) => 
            new { Id = x.Id, firstName = x.firstName, lastName = x.lastName, RoleId = x.RoleId, Controller = y.Controller, 
                Action = y.Action }).Where(z => z.Id == currentUser && z.Controller == controller && z.Action == action)
                .SingleOrDefault();

            if (user != null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have extended the default implementation of `Authorize`, you need to use `[CustomAuthorize(Role="Admin,Supervisor")]`. This will set the roles. You can then access the `Roles` property directly in your code as they are contained in the parent `AuthorizeAttribute` which has been inherited.

```
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var roles = Roles;
        if (AuthorizeRequest(actionContext))
        {

            return;

        }

        HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }
```

Comment: How can I access the parameter roles in my customauthorize?? please give me a sample. And I don't have any codes yet that access it.

Comment: @KennethAvecilla You can just do 'Roles'. It will be directly accessible. As it is already defined in the parent class

Comment: I don't get it. Please explain it clearly or show some code. Please!

Comment: does it mean that the value of roles is equal to the parameter (Role="Admin,Supervisor") ??

Comment: @KennethAvecilla Yes. You can even try and see he value at debug time.